# MSVC++ 2010 Express linker error LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, linker

I have a few files in my project that aren't working the way I want them to.

Basically, I have a class, called Entity. It's defined in **Entity.h** and the functions are in **Entity.cpp**, so that's all swell. I then have a child class, called PlayerShip. It's defined the same way, in two files.

(**Entity.h** is included in **PlayerShip.h**)

When I include **PlayerShip.h** in **playership.cpp** AND in **main.cpp** the linker throws a LNK2005 error - the constructor is defined twice. Technically though, wasn't it just prototyped twice?

***main.cpp***

```
-- snip --

#include "PlayerShip.h"
using namespace std;

-- snip --

// PLAYER
int playerFlags = DRAW | EVENT | LOGIC;
playerShip pship = playerShip(playerFlags, iManager.getImage("ship.png"), 4);
Entity* player = eManager.addEntity(&pship);

etc, int main() yada yada yada
```

***PlayerShip.h***

```
#include "entity.h"

class playerShip : public Entity
{
private:
    int horizontalSpeed, verticalSpeed;
    int moveSpeed;

public:
    playerShip(int allow, const sf::Image &img, int speed);
    void handleLogic();
    void handleEvents(sf::Event ev, sf::RenderWindow *screen);
};
```

***playership.cpp***

```
#include "PlayerShip.h"

playerShip::playerShip(int allow, const sf::Image &img, int speed) : Entity(allow, img), horizontalSpeed(0), verticalSpeed(0)
{
moveSpeed = speed;
}

void playerShip::handleEvents(sf::Event ev, sf::RenderWindow *screen)
{
while (screen->GetEvent(ev))
{
    if (ev.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if (ev.Key.Code == sf::Key::Left)
            horizontalSpeed = -1 * moveSpeed;
        if (ev.Key.Code == sf::Key::Right)
            horizontalSpeed = 1 * moveSpeed;
        if (ev.Key.Code == sf::Key::Up)
            verticalSpeed = -1 * moveSpeed;
        if (ev.Key.Code == sf::Key::Down)
            verticalSpeed = 1 * moveSpeed;
    }
}
}

void playerShip::handleLogic()
{
setX(float(getX()+horizontalSpeed));
setY(float(getY()+verticalSpeed));
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening. =S

Comment: Do you also `#include entity.h` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: @user Could you post the exact linker error message?

Comment: If you include both "PlayerShip.h" and "Entity.h" in main.cpp, then you have to protect the header files with [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: yeah, i use include guards... maybe it's a misuse of virtual members?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have forgotten include guards or using pragma once. These will make sure that the header will only be read once witch is good.

Include guard example:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

class Entity
...

#endif // ENTITY_H
```

Pragma once:

```
#pragma once

class Entity
...
```

Note that pragma once isn't standard but is still supported by practically all compilers.

Comment: In that case I can't really see what's wrong with it... Maybe seeing what the Entity class looks like could help or the linker error itself(although I doubt that would help that much)... Also sometimes there is nothing wrong with the code and VS just got it wrong somehow. The only solution then is to do a rebuild...